# Filtering in Many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I am taking a popular example here for convenience:
Let's say we have a list of students and a list of courses. There is a many to many relationship between them. I can use an intermediate table to define relationship between the 2.

What I need help with is this:
I want to provide a course name as input, and figure out the students who are studying the 'input' course are studying what other courses.

Example:

| Student | Course |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | C1 |
| S1 | C2 |
| S2 | C1 |
| S3 | C2 |
| S3 | C3 |
| S4 | C2 |
| S5 | C6 |
| S5 | C2 |

Input: C2
So S1, S3, S4, S5 are studying C2. I want to find what other courses are they studying.
Output: C1, C3, C6

I'm looking for concepts or code to implement something like this in mySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do self-join

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.Course 
FROM (
    SELECT Student 
    FROM T t1  
    WHERE Course = 'C2'
) t1 
INNER JOIN T t2 ON t1.Student = t2.Student 
WHERE t2.Course <> 'C2'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0036cc/3/0)**:

```
| Course |
|--------|
|     C1 |
|     C3 |
|     C6 |
```

Comment: Subquery is excess. `SELECT DISTINCT t2.Course FROM T t1 INNER JOIN T t2 USING (Student) WHERE t1.Course = 'C2' AND t2.Course <> 'C2'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Course
FROM mytable
WHERE Student IN (SELECT Student FROM mytable WHERE Course='C2')
GROUP BY Course;
```

Or if you want to exclude the input:

```
SELECT Course
FROM mytable
WHERE Student IN (SELECT Student FROM mytable WHERE Course='C2')
AND Course != 'C2'
GROUP BY Course;
```

Or multiple inputs:

```
SELECT Course
FROM mytable
WHERE Student IN (SELECT Student FROM mytable WHERE Course IN ('C2','C3'))
#AND Course NOT IN ('C2','C3')
GROUP BY Course;
```